# Need help in write firestore database security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-security

I am new to firestore database and I have developed an app in android studio accessing data from firestore database. My application has 2 types of user category 1. Admin 2. Users
I have implemented Mobile number authentication logic using API of sms service provider. I am not using google's firebase authentication. How should I write the rules for the firestore database I am unable to understand.

Admin --> can read and write to all collections

Users --> can read all collections but write only few collections

Can anyone guide me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good place to start is here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started